# Can't find a specific link using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble extracting specific links from a webpage using BeautifulSoup. The specific webpage is http://punchdrink.com/recipe-archives/?filter-spirit__term=Gin

When I inspect the source code, I see the links that I want to grab, specifically the links to recipes (example: http://punchdrink.com/recipes/breakfast-martini/), but when I use BeautifulSoup, these links don't show up in the HTML at all.

Here's my code for grabbing the HTML:

```
def drinkScraper(url, searchTerm):
  res = requests.get(url)
  res.raise_for_status()
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
```

printing soup gives html with no reference to any of the links to recipes on that page.

I'm trying to scrape this website for links to all of the recipes in their archive, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Because it is a dynamic website, you have inspect the Ajax request to get the urls.

Comment: @amigcamel Thank you! I ended up using selenium to find the links. I'll look into your suggestion more for the future though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although as stated you can use `selenium`, you can also learn well by following `XHR` requests and emulating them via `requests`. If you notice when opening Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, when searching for a term, it'll request an api (via XHR) and return your results in `json` format. You can simply request the parameters and parse the results.

Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

jsonRequestData = '{"requests":[{"indexName":"wp_posts_recipe","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=1000&maxValuesPerFacet=100&page=0&distinct=false&facetingAfterDistinct=true&filters=record_index%3D0&facets=%5B%22spirit%22%2C%22style%22%2C%22season%22%2C%22flavor_profile%22%2C%22family%22%5D&tagFilters=&facetFilters=%5B%22spirit%3AGin%22%5D"}]}'
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post('http://h0iee3ergc-2.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%20(lite)%203.21.1%3Binstantsearch.js%201.11.6%3BJS%20Helper%202.19.0&x-algolia-application-id=H0IEE3ERGC&x-algolia-api-key=9a128c4989675ec375c59a2de9ef3fc1', headers=headers, data=jsonRequestData)

for hit in response.json()["results"][0]["hits"]:
    print ("%s (%s)" % (hit["post_title"], hit["permalink"]))
```

Where `jsonRequestData` is the data `form post data`, where you can change the search term and `headers` is the headers that you want to send.

It'll output:

```
State Street Bloody Mary (http://punchdrink.com/recipes/state-street-bloody-mary/)
I'm Ya Huckleberry (http://punchdrink.com/recipes/im-ya-huckleberry/)
Girl From Cadiz (http://punchdrink.com/recipes/girl-from-cadiz/)
Breakfast Martini (http://punchdrink.com/recipes/breakfast-martini/)
Juniperotivo (http://punchdrink.com/recipes/juniperotivo/)
....
```